# How can I insert this graphic?

Tags: graphics

The image goes between the \title and the \author. I want to include an image with pdf format.

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]

\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.20\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
    \insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{\insertshortinstitute}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.65\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
    Examen Final - CICN
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
   \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}
    02 - 12 - 2022 % DELETED
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\title{Examen Final \\ Computación e Introducción al Cálculo Numérico}

\author[]{Caleb Franco}

\institute[FI - CRUC-IUA]{ Facultad de Ingeniería \\ 
    Centro Regional Universitario Córdoba - IUA \\
Universidad de la Defensa Nacional}

\date[]{\scriptsize 02 - 12 - 2022}


    
%\tikzstyle{my arrow} = [draw=cyan!75, very thick, single arrow, 
%minimum height=4.5cm, shape border rotate =#1, fill=gray!10]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------- titlepage frame ------------------------% Slide 1
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
    

    \textsc{\tbl{\Huge Problema 1:}}
    
    
    
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My front page looks like this.
[image]

The best try I have is this, but I want it right here (where the arrow points).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\title{Examen Final \\ Computación e Introducción al Cálculo Numérico \\[2ex]
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image.pdf}}
```

[image]